# Using :order and :limit options - Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any way I can use the :limit and :order options in the find method. I'm trying to sort activities by descending order, such that the newest activities are shown. However, when I try to use the (:all, :limit => 5, :order=> 'Date desc) I get an error.  I need to limit to only 5 records, and when I disregard the order option, it works but not what I need...

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you missed a quote in your example.

> Model.find(:all, :limit => 5, :order=> 'created_at desc')

Make sure that a date column exists in your table.

Comment: I've tried this, but I get this error

An expression in the ORDER BY clause in the following position, or starting with "DATE" in the "ORDER BY" clause is not valid.  Reason code = "2".  SQLSTATE=42822

Comment: It might not be called "Date". Try "date", "created_at" or "updated_at".

Answer (score 0):

Is your date column actually called `date`? First, I would change that, date is the name of a function in most databases, that could be the cause of the error you are seeing. Rails uses `created_at`, `updated_at`, etc, so following that naming scheme will make your code more readable to future maintainers.

You could try to quote the column name in back-ticks:

```
:order => "`date` desc"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue isn't with regards to the date column, it works perfectly when I do not use the :limit option, it does sort by date descending. I know the column name isn't desirable, but it cannot be changed now. 

The limit option works when I use it without the order option and vice versa

Comment: Can you post the log of what SQL is trying to be executed?